# Shift Left or Right on a variable of std_logic_vector

Tags: vhdl

I am wondering if it is possible to perform a shift right or shift left on a variable of type std_logic_vector

when I use a signal instead of a variable I usually use the shift_left or shift_right functions but I have tried using it on them but it does not work or maybe I am doing it wrong.

e.g. `variable a : std_logic_vector(16 downto 0);`

Comment: In VHDL2008:
`sla` - shift left arithmetic
`sra` - shift right arithmetic
`sll` - shift left logic
`srl` - shift right logic

Answer (score 0):

The shift operators (`sla`, `sra`, `sll`, and `srl`) are all defined for the *type*, independent of the instance (`signal` or `variable`).  Indeed, these operators can be used anywhere the type is referenced, even for a `constant`,  `record`, etc.

For example, say you have:

```
type my_record is record
  a : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
  b : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0):
end record my_record;
```

And a couple of instances, such as:

```
architecture behav of foo is
  signal x : my_record;
begin

  process
    variable y : my_record;
  begin
    y.a := y.a sll 1;
    y.b := x.b srl 1;
  end process;
end architecture behav;
```

Note that the operators can be used on any instance of that type.  This is even acceptable for subprograms, such as:

```
function myfunc(a : std_logic_vector) return std_logic_vector is
begin
  return (a sll 5);
end function myfunc;
```